# SQL Select Statement: One Child - Two Parents (two different FK)

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I have the situation where the best to explain it is through the following scenario:

- where a `Child` record has two `Parent`s (Mother and Father)

If you later to read this post consider the option to apply the `self-referencing tables` scenario, it is not necessary, there are no neither grandfathers nor grandsons.

About the **parent** it is defined how:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent(
  code varchar(3),
  name varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(code)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The records are inserted how:

```
INSERT INTO parent(code,name) VALUES('001','Mary');
INSERT INTO parent(code,name) VALUES('002','Joseph');
INSERT INTO parent(code,name) VALUES('003','Adan');
INSERT INTO parent(code,name) VALUES('004','Eva');
INSERT INTO parent(code,name) VALUES('005','Ana');
INSERT INTO parent(code,name) VALUES('006','Elcana');
```

And the `select` query works how is expected:

```
mysql> select * from parent;
+------+--------+
| code | name   |
+------+--------+
| 001  | Mary   |
| 002  | Joseph |
| 003  | Adan   |
| 004  | Eva    |
| 005  | Ana    |
| 006  | Elcana |
+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

About the **child** it is defined how:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS child(
  code varchar(3),
  name varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(code),
  mother_code varchar(3),
  father_code varchar(3),
  FOREIGN KEY fk_mother_code(mother_code) REFERENCES parent(code),
  FOREIGN KEY fk_father_code(father_code) REFERENCES parent(code)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**Observation:** from above observe the `Child` expects **two** `PK`s from the `Parent` (assume that must be different) through two `FK`s.

The records are inserted how:

```
INSERT INTO child(code, name, mother_code, father_code) VALUES('001','Jesus', '001', '002');
INSERT INTO child(code, name, mother_code, father_code) VALUES('002','Cain', '003', '004');
INSERT INTO child(code, name, mother_code, father_code) VALUES('003','Abel', '003', '004');
INSERT INTO child(code, name, mother_code, father_code) VALUES('004','Set', '003', '004');
INSERT INTO child(code, name, mother_code, father_code) VALUES('005','Samuel', '005', '006');
```

And the `select` query works how is expected:

```
mysql> select * from child;
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| code | name   | mother_code | father_code |
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| 001  | Jesus  | 001         | 002         |
| 002  | Cain   | 003         | 004         |
| 003  | Abel   | 003         | 004         |
| 004  | Set    | 003         | 004         |
| 005  | Samuel | 005         | 006         |
+------+--------+-------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The goal is get the following:

```
+------+--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| code | name   | code | name  | mother_code | father_code |
+------+--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| 001  | Mary   | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
| 002  | Joseph | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
+------+--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT p.*, c.* FROM parent p,
                     child c,
                     (SELECT pm.code AS m_code FROM parent pm) AS m,
                     (SELECT pf.code AS f_code FROM parent pf) AS f
                WHERE
                     m.m_code='001' AND
                     f.f_code='002' AND
                     c.mother_code=m.m_code AND
                     c.father_code=f.f_code AND
                     c.mother_code='001' AND
                     c.father_code='002' AND
                     c.code='001';
```

The `where` clause would look redundant and it is because I am trying to get the desired result, thus it contains attempts to write correct the query.

But always returns:

```
+------+--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| code | name   | code | name  | mother_code | father_code |
+------+--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| 001  | Mary   | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
| 002  | Joseph | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
| 003  | Adan   | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
| 004  | Eva    | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
| 005  | Ana    | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
| 006  | Elcana | 001  | Jesus | 001         | 002         |
+------+--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thus what is the correct sentence?

Comment: Are you just trying to show the top 2 results? What makes your result not the desired result?

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: No the top, just one child and the two parents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected result I think this is what you need:

```
select
  p.code, p.name,
  c.code, c.name,
  c.mother_code, c.father_code
from parent p 
inner join child c 
on c.mother_code = p.code or c.father_code = p.code
```

You can add any condition you need with a WHERE clause.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7R2QVvCUcqAPjL7TEPxS1d/0).
Results:

```
| code | name   | code | name   | mother_code | father_code |
| ---- | ------ | ---- | ------ | ----------- | ----------- |
| 001  | Mary   | 001  | Jesus  | 001         | 002         |
| 002  | Joseph | 001  | Jesus  | 001         | 002         |
| 003  | Adan   | 002  | Cain   | 003         | 004         |
| 004  | Eva    | 002  | Cain   | 003         | 004         |
| 003  | Adan   | 003  | Abel   | 003         | 004         |
| 004  | Eva    | 003  | Abel   | 003         | 004         |
| 003  | Adan   | 004  | Set    | 003         | 004         |
| 004  | Eva    | 004  | Set    | 003         | 004         |
| 005  | Ana    | 005  | Samuel | 005         | 006         |
| 006  | Elcana | 005  | Samuel | 005         | 006         |
```

Comment: I got the same result, I need add the `where` clause because I need just the two first records

Comment: From what I understand the condition should be something like: `WHERE c.name = 'Jesus'`

Comment: Yes, your output lets see the format I requested, showing two lines that represent the mother and father

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for two `join`s?

```
select c.*, pm.name as mother_name, pf.name as father_name
from child c join
     parent pm
     on c.mother_code = pm.code join
     parent pf
     on c.father_code = pf.code;
```

You can add a `where` clause to filter this down to particular children:

```
where c.code in ('001', '002')
```

Comment: Seems the path is by here, but your query returns 5 records, I will add the `where` clause

Answer (score 1):

If the dependency is on the child to get the parents, use or on your join.

```
SELECT p.Code, p.[Name], c.Code, p.[Name], c.Mother_Code, c.Father_Code
FROM Parent p JOIN Child c ON c.Mother_Code = p.Code OR c.Father_Code = p.Code
WHERE c.name = 'Jesus'
```

If the dependency is to find a parent's children, then just alter the WHERE statement

```
SELECT p.Code, p.[Name], c.Code, p.[Name], c.Mother_Code, c.Father_Code
FROM Parent p JOIN Child c ON c.Mother_Code = p.Code OR c.Father_Code = p.Code
WHERE p.name IN ('Mary', 'Joseph')
```